# Programming in Gazebo using source code

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I am writing a comparison between V-REP and Gazebo simulators. I have used V-REP in simulation, but I have not used Gazebo. I want to know if I can simulate a robot without coding in ROS?.. I mean can I write my program using source code in Gazebo? if the answer is No, why? thanks for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23522/programming-in-gazebo-using-source-code/) by [Nana](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14863/nana/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, you can write plugins in C++ which are independent of ROS. See [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_hello_world&cat=write_plugin).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nana](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14863/nana/) on 2019-08-21**:
Thank you for your helpful response.